# React forwarding application component

Tags: reactjs, dependency-injection, react-props

I have few react classes and i should forward App ref:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    /** @public */
    testCase = "Woooa dis is test!";

    render() {
        return <MySimpleClass application={this}/>;
    }
}

class MySimpleClass extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <MyAnotherClass application={this.props.application}/>;
    }
}

class MyAnotherClass extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <AndAnotherClass application={this.props.application}/>;
    }
}

class AndAnotherClass extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.application.testCase}</div>;
    }
}
```

Question: how i can use *forwarding* without annoying property declaration? And without storing App ref as global context variable (`(ref) => window.app = ref`). I need something like dependency injection or createComponentFactory (where i can manually add needed props) or lifecycle hooks? Internet tolds just about react-for-beginners...

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like `singleton` pattern

```
class App extends React.Component {

    static instance = null;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        if (App.instance == null)
            App.instance = this;
    }


    testCase = "Woooa dis is test!";

    render() {
        return <MySimpleClass/>;
    }
}
```

now you can access the instance any where else after initiating `App` class

so in `MySimpleClass` , `MyAnotherClass` , `AndAnotherClass` you can do this

```
render(){
    let app = App.instance;
}
```

Comment: No its just like global context... I need injection into props.